# subtract x columns in one df from x columns in another and maintain other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have three string columns and three value columns in two separate dfs. I am trying to subtract the values in the one df from the values in the other while maintaining the string columns. If an entry is in one df but not the other, I need to keep it and and subtract 0 or vice versa. Code below simplified, but in my actual df I have `.fillna(0)` to solve for the 0s.

```
data_start = [['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3], ['d', 'e', 'f', 4, 5, 6]]
data_end = [['a', 'b', 'c', 8, 9, 10], ['d', 'g', 'r', 11, 0, 5]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_start, columns=['lvl1', 'lvl2', 'lvl3', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_end, columns=['lvl1', 'lvl2', 'lvl3', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3'])

for x in df1.iloc[:,-3:]:
    for x in df2.iloc[:,-3:]:
        df_new = df2[x].subtract(df1[x], fill_value=0)

df_new = pd.DataFrame(df_new)
```

Output is:

```
  val3
0    7
1   -1
```

Desired output is:

```
  lvl1  lvl2 lvl3 val1 val2 val3
0    a     b    c    7    7    7
1    d     e    f   -4   -5   -6
2    d     g    r   11    0    5
```

Comment: _I am trying to subtract the values in the one df from the values in the other while maintaining the string columns._ What do you mean by _maintain_ ? Please provide a clear description of the operation you're trying to perform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the same index on both `DataFrame`s then you can use normal arithmetic.

```
keys = ['lvl1', 'lvl2', 'lvl3'] 
df1 = df1.set_index(keys)
df2 = df2.set_index(keys)
df2 - df1
#                 val1  val2  val3
# lvl1 lvl2 lvl3                  
# a    b    c      7.0   7.0   7.0
# d    e    f      NaN   NaN   NaN
#      g    r      NaN   NaN   NaN
```

To use `0` for missing values in the subtraction, you can use the [subtract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html) method and the `fill_value` parameter. Then `reset_index` will flatten the result back out.

```
df2.subtract(df1, fill_value=0).reset_index()
#   lvl1 lvl2 lvl3  val1  val2  val3
# 0    a    b    c   7.0   7.0   7.0
# 1    d    e    f  -4.0  -5.0  -6.0
# 2    d    g    r  11.0   0.0   5.0
```

If you want to keep integer values, you can cast before resetting the index.

```
df2.subtract(df1, fill_value=0).astype(int).reset_index()
#   lvl1 lvl2 lvl3  val1  val2  val3
# 0    a    b    c     7     7     7
# 1    d    e    f    -4    -5    -6
# 2    d    g    r    11     0     5
```